# Continued fraction of $π$ using sums of cubes

Tags: pi, continued-fractions

Recently I came across this identity:
$$\pi=3+\cfrac1{6+\cfrac{1^3+2^3}{6+\cfrac{1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3}{6+\cfrac{1^3+2^3+3^3+4^3+5^3+6^3}{6+\ddots}}}},\tag1$$
thus
$$\pi=3+\cfrac{1}{6+\cfrac{(1\cdot3)^2}{6+\cfrac{(2\cdot5)^2}{6+\cfrac{(3\cdot7)^2}{6+\ddots}}}}.\tag2$$
We also know that
$$\pi=3+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)(2n+1)},\tag3$$
Converting the sum to a continued fraction we get:
$$\pi=3+\cfrac{1}{6\cdot1^2+\cfrac{(1\cdot2\cdot3)^2}{6\cdot2^2+\cfrac{(2\cdot3\cdot5)^2}{6\cdot3^2+\cfrac{(3\cdot4\cdot7)^2}{6\cdot4^2+\ddots}}}}.\tag4$$
Are the two continued fractions $(2)$ and $(4)$ really equal? And how is the above continued fraction using sums of cubes derived?

Comment: The sum-of-cubes formula was written up by  Tony Foster, available  at https://pdfcoffee.com/a-continued-fraction-for-pi-containing-cubes-author-tony-foster-pdf-free.html  .  He did algebraic magic starting with numerators that were squares of triangular numbers.

Comment: I should add that I've verified numerically it diverges, as does a couple continued fraction forms earlier on in Foster's derivation. He tried to make a simplified (not "simple")  continued fraction after converting the Nilakantha infinite series into a nonsimple continued fraction.

Answer (score 4):

The first two identities $(1),(2)$ are **wrong**; the continued fraction with "sums of cubes" **doesn't converge**. This can be shown using the known [criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Simple_convergence_concepts): for a sequence $\{a_n\}$ of positive real numbers, the continued fraction $$a_0+\cfrac{1}{a_1+\cfrac{1}{a_2+\cfrac{1}{\ldots}}}$$ converges if and only if the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ *diverges*. In our case, for $n>0$, we [have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#The_equivalence_transformation) $a_n=6c_n$ where $c_1=1$ and $c_{n+1}=1/\big(n^2(2n+1)^2 c_n\big)$, and one obtains $\color{blue}{a_n=\mathcal{O}(1/n^2)}$ using, say, the $\Gamma$-function: $$c_n=d_n\left(\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac14\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac34\right)}\right)^2\quad\implies\quad d_{n+1}=\frac{1}{64d_n},$$ giving $d_n=\mathcal{O}(1)$ and $c_n=\mathcal{O}(1/n^2)$ since [$\Gamma(x+a)/\big(x^a\Gamma(x)\big)\underset{x\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General).

For curiosity, here are computed approximate values of the lower/upper limits, respectively:
$$\mathtt{3.14221404702232210406367353362166370131484883936217-}\\\mathtt{3.15126273205858662275081482878228893534757749143403-}$$

Comment: @mathlover   The sum-of-cubes formula was written up by  Tony Foster, available  at https://pdfcoffee.com/a-continued-fraction-for-pi-containing-cubes-author-tony-foster-pdf-free.html  .  He did algebraic magic starting with numerators that were squares of triangular numbers.

Comment: @metamorphy I've put tags on the OP's equation to clarify that both forms (1) and (2) are wrong. P.S. I haven't checked the last form (4).